# Why is Visual Studio saying this cast from System.Int32 to System.Byte is redundant?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to retrieve a type of `Byte` for a unit test, yet when I do a simple cast as shown below, I get [the code analysis info in VS that the cast is redundant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0004).  Why?  Clearly the cast is needed to keep the result from returning `System.Int32` instead of `System.Byte`.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're attempting to do here, buy why not simply do `var y = typeof(byte);`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - code is most likly simplified to show the issue at hand

Comment: I'm attempting to do exactly what I'm doing.  I'm aware I can do what you suggest, but that's not the question.

Comment: It's because you have a constant the the code analysis knows will fit into a byte, so it "knows" with 100% certainty that you don't need to cast it. But it is incorrect because removing the cast changes the behaviour - therefore I agree that this is a code analysis false positive. In other words: I think it's a bug.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - if compiler error, shouldn't it be present in the error list window? seems like an analyzer issue, or? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY6zd.png (note: the 2 messages are something differently, wanted to test if static extension method produce the same behaviour)

Comment: @RandRandom It's an error *in* the compiler (well, the relevant Roslyn analyzer), not an error raised *by* the compiler

Comment: @RandRandom The IDE code analysis is not done by the compiler - there's a separate assembly for it.

Comment: You can configure the severity of such a diagnostic to be either an error or warning, but the point is nevertheless that the analyzer is clearly wrong

Comment: Raise it as an issue? I couldn't find one already raised. https://github.com/dotnet/rosyln/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but my best guess is that because the value you want to cast is compile-time known it let's you know that semantics will be the same. That is true as long you don't use reflection to get type info.